# How to pass application credentials through apollo client like we do with axios auth options

Tags: node.js, graphql, axios, react-apollo, apollo-client

I wanted to know how to pass application credentials (or even user credentials through code) to apollo client like we do in axios.

In axios -

```
const data = await axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: `${SOME_URL}`,
  auth: {
    username: USER,   //like this//
    password: PASS,
  },
  data: req.body,
  headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
});
```

For apollo client I have used apollo-link-http, my setup looks like this -

```
import fetch from "unfetch";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { from } from "apollo-link";
import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([errorLink, standardVariablesLink, typenameCleanerLink, createHttpLink({ uri: "https://graphql-backend/graphql", fetch })]),
  cache,
});
```

I have tried adding [credentials option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-http#options) in createHttpLink object as `credentials:` `${USER}:${PASS}` OR as an object

```
credentials: {
  user: USER,
  password: PASS
}
```

but that didn't work.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: @xadm I have been searching the docs for a week, but couldn't find anything related to it. Instead there were alternatives suggested like use cookies but that's not an option I can take. The other methods suggested, I have tried but it's not working as I mentioned in question.

Comment: @xadm Yes, that worked. Thanks. Can you add an answer so that I can vote and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question:

**What is this `auth` in axios?** ... a bit of searching: **basic auth** options! `axios` internally converts it to header.

Apollo client is not so nice ... you need to convert params into header itself and use this way:

```
 const link = createHttpLink({   
   headers: {     
     authorization: "Basic btoa_converted_username_password";   
   },
```

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't knew that axios turned those auth option to normal authorizaition headers.

Answer (score 2):

The `auth` option in `axios` is just a shorthand way of constructing a [Basic Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization). In order to construct the credentials value to include in the header, you do the following:

> - The username and the password are combined with a colon (aladdin:opensesame).
> - The resulting string is base64 encoded (YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l).

So you can do something like:

```
createHttpLink({
  uri: '...',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${window.btoa(`${username}:${password}`)}`,
  }
})
```

If you're running this code in Node.js, you would use the following instead of `btoa`:

```
Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`).toString('base64')
```

Also note that if this code is running client-side, you probably want to inject the headers dynamically by using [setContext](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/context/) instead.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem. I am using it on client-side, Is there a way that those resulted string (base64 encoded) does not appear in headers in network tab or something, because if someone picks it up from there, it can be used to get the credentials.

Comment: When developing a client app, you shouldn't embed any credentials in your code, period, since your code is public and anyone can read it. If you're using basic auth as part of a client app, then the user should provide the credentials somehow. Even then and even when done over HTTPS, [using basic auth is generally inadvisable](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https).